# Is a lock statement needed within a class derived from BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a class that inherits from `BackgroundWorker` to do some specific stuff on a remote server.  I've added properties for this class to store information needed for the job to complete.  Example:

```
 public class GenerateFileWorker : System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
{
    public string LocalFileName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set;  }

    public GenerateFileWorker() {}

    public GenerateFileWorker(string username, string password, string localFileName)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        LocalFileName = localFileName;
    }
    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    // ... 
}
```

I know `lock` is needed to safely access objects outside the class, but what about within?  Do I need it when accessing the properties of the current instance within `OnDoWork()`?

Comment: What if somebody outside the class try to manipulate your properties while the inside of the class is also trying to access it on another thread? Whether or not you should put a lock as nothing to do about whether the code is inside or outside a class

Comment: And how do you use those properties? Do you write to them anywhere outside constructor?

Comment: `I know lock is needed to safely access objects outside the class` No, a `lock` is needed whenever you're trying to access mutable state from multiple threads (or at least it's one of many ways of synchronizing access to shared state).  It has nothing to do with what class you access the data from.

Comment: @HeatherKordinak - I think you need to look up the `lock` documentation. It sounds like you don't exactly know how to use them.

Comment: *I know lock is needed to safely access objects outside the class* No no no: Absolutely incorrect. People write classes all the time which do not access objects outside the class but that does NOT mean thread safety is not needed.

Comment: @litelite That is what I realize now.  I made the properties private and am working around the issue that made me think I needed them.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes I did, and no I didn't.

Comment: @Servy Thank you so much for succinctly explaining, it was helpful.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I am not debating the necessity of thread safety, hence me even posting the question.  What I do try to avoid is overkill, which is why I asked if it was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a question of what class you're inheriting from. It's a question of whether multiple threads may concurrently read or modify properties or fields so that they interfere with each other, or one thread reads while another is in the middle of updating something. That's when you would need a `lock` (or some other mechanism) to ensure that such conflicts don't occur. (That's an oversimplification for brevity.)

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread.

The idea is that the UI thread only interacts with the background thread by canceling it, getting progress reports from it, or being notified that it has finished or failed. It doesn't directly access the variables (state) used within the process.

One thing in your class that stands out is this:

```
public string LocalFileName { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set;  }
```

Because those are read/write properties it's possible that the UI thread could update them while the background thread is using them. I imagine that's probably not your intent. Do those properties need to be writable? Or do they even need to be properties at all? (If they don't need to be properties, do you need to inherit?)

Perhaps you can initialize variables containing those values at the beginning of the background process. Now those variables are private within the method executed by the background process, which means that it's not possible for the UI thread or any other thread to interact with them.

Comment: Now that I'm getting further into this making the properties private seems the way to go.  Needing to modify them outside of initialization would be rare.